# Run Batch file As Admin (PSEXEC)

Tags: batch-file, cmd, psexec

I have Batch file that need ADMIN Privilege to run (My ADMIN have Password).

So I Have 2 Batch File to run (This method is working but I need to run only in 1 Batch File for Result capturing in VBA):

(1) `C:\PSTools\psexec.exe \\PECPC021 -u PECPC021\Administrator -p P@ssw0rd245 "C:\Temp\Exec.bat"` This for Run As Admin With Password.

(2) `reg query "\\PECPC108\HKU\S-1-5-21-3026626878-399171236-2381696588-1976\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\internet settings" /s | find /i "ProxyServer"` This command need Admin Privilege (Exec.bat).

Result for 2 Batch running : https://imagebin.ca/v/3eqd7kkWRmBw

When Combining these 2 command in 1 batch file, its give an error. My command :

```
C:\PSTools\psexec.exe \\PECPC021 -u PECPC021\Administrator -p P@ssw0rd245 "reg query ""\\PECPC108\HKU\S-1-5-21-3026626878-399171236-2381696588-1976\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\internet settings"" /s | find /i ""ProxyServer"""
```

And Error Msg : https://imagebin.ca/v/3eqaEEAyeqpU

Comment: What is the content of `exec.bat`?  Can you just add the `reg query` to the end of that batch file without the psexec call?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need you open cmd as administrator.

Press `WINDOWS`, type `cmd`, right click on `cmd` and select run as administrator.

Type the file that you want to run in the command line.
Example: `C:\Users\xx\desktop\exec.bat` and press `Enter`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have password, you can use the following command:

```
runas /noprofile /user:mymachine\administrator yourfile
```

It will ask for the password.

Comment: using this inside an elevated psexec session on a remote PC - it does not pause for password entry, just goes straight to the command prompt without executing the [yourfile]